# Adding multiple widgets into 1 cell?

Tags: gwt, flextable

Using either FlexTable or Grid, I want to add multiple FlowPanel's into 1 cell. I know this can be achieved by adding the multiple FlowPanel's into 1 (parent) FlowPanel and adding the parent panel to the cell.

Just wondering if there is a way to add these multiple widgets into 1 cell, without wrapping them into a (parent) flow panel?

(As in the below example, I do not want the parent div and instead, I want the child div's to appear directly under the  tag.)

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <td>
            <div id="I-DO-NOT-WANT-THIS-PARENT-DIV">
                <div id="CHILD1"></div>
                <div id="CHILD2"></div>
                <div id="CHILD3"></div>
                <div id="CHILD4"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </TR>   
</TABLE>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what sort algorithm brought you to implement something like this. I don't think its possible, each cell is designed like that. Anyway you got possibly 2 way to solve this: #1. build your own flex table using a absolute panel as cell container and overriding and copying all method [In my opinion never do it]. #2. Is brief exactly what your problem, which make you to think something like this, [hoping a good explanation for you query]. Anyway thanks for your time to spending on this comment. :)

Comment: The only reason is, the way I want to create the Table is with the assumption that I have 1 Row and multiple Columns. And in each column I have different controls that need to be placed. I did not want to create multiple rows (one for each div), as per our UI design restrictions.

Comment: Are you looking for merging cells kind of a thing ??

Comment: @user1730159 : Are you saying that, you want to add different components to each column having different handlers for each components OR different handler for each cell?!!!

Comment: To elaborate a little bit on what I am trying to do, going by the above table structure, for example, I can possibly have my company logo in CHILD1, a Table with a few buttons in CHILD2, an accordian with my navigation links in CHILD3 etc...etc..And I want all these controls placed one below the other (right inside the <td></td> tag) with no other parent panel holding them together.  Hope this information helps in understanding what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the dom and move the elements to their grand-parent. With gwtquery is is easy:

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
...
final FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.add(new Label("1"));
panel.add(new Label("2"));
panel.add(new Label("3"));

final FlexTable table = new FlexTable();
table.setWidget(0, 0, panel);
RootPanel.get().add(table);

$(panel).children().appendTo($(panel).parent());
```

If you want, with gquery you could even promote the `<td>`of the table to a `Panel` and continue adding widgets to it:

```
HTMLPanel newpanel = $(panel).parent().as(Widgets).panel().widget();
panel.removeFromParent();
newpanel.add(new Label("4"));
```

Comment: I am sure it will work but I don't want to do any DOM manipulation. I wanted to see if there's a straight forward GWT solution, like, if there is any FlexTable or Grid API that I am not aware of. Anyways, Thanks for the solution.

Comment: There is no GWT-core solution for this, all widgets based on tables accept an unique widget per cell.